# R: Sum each column by subgroup

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a matrix of plant species occurrence data. The matrix is set up so that every column is a species, and every row is a sampling location. I also have identifiers that group sampling locations based on certain environmental variables. I would like to create columns sums for each species, but subgrouped by the specific environmental variables.

An example data set:

```
library(vegan)
data("dune")
data("dune.env")
dune$plot <- c(1:20); dune.env$plot <- c(1:20)
merge(dune, dune.env)
```

So there are now 20 plots, with 30 species observed, and 5 associated environmental variables. I would like to generate the sum of the number of individuals observed per species, grouped by "Management". I have tried something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
sums <- group_by(data, data$Management) %>% colSums(data[,(2:31)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

but I always get an error about incorrect dims. I am not sure how I would go about solving my problem. Ideally, the result would be a dataframe with 4 rows (1 for each management type) where all the species (cols 2:31) have been summed.

Comment: it seems to me that you could benefit from converting your wide table to a long one (see `?reshape`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowsums` does what you need:

```
dat <- merge(dune, dune.env)

> rowsum(dat[,2:31], dat$Management)
   Achimill Agrostol Airaprae Alopgeni Anthodor Bellpere Bromhord Chenalbu   ...
BF        7        0        0        2        4        5        8        0   ...    
HF        6        7        0        8        9        2        4        0   ...     
NM        2       13        5        0        8        2        0        0   ...     
SF        1       28        0       26        0        4        3        1   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
a <- merge(dune, dune.env)
setDT(a)
a[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = Management, .SDcols = names(a)[2:31]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was doing something very similar a few days ago:
[How to obtain species richness and abundance for sites with multiple samples using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547792/how-to-obtain-species-richness-and-abundance-for-sites-with-multiple-samples-usi)

To modify the excellent answer given by @akrun:

```
  df <- merge(dune, dune.env)
  library(dplyr)
  df2<- df %>% 
      group_by(Management) %>% 
      summarise_at(sum, .vars = vars(Achimill:Callcusp))
```